AppSheet Create and Show PDF file
In my AppSheet app I make pdf file by automation bot, It works perfectly I created file and I got path (like Folder path and file ptefix) this path I use in "File" row of my relative data tables whis tgis path I can see my new created pdf file into app.
It works. Also I see my file in Drive directory.But if I make changes in App data I yes see them in file that storage in directory but don't see if I open file by preesed File in view it shows old version, first version of created file, not version after changing.
I tried removing the "File" row data (old path) but it makes a change in pdf file into Drive directory but doesn't change if I open the file from App.
I see an old file if I open it from the App.

Can you share the sample data of your Data Tables, screen shot of steps and runs what are you watching things that will help the community understand and replicate your issue? Also I am wondering what type of changes you are referring to, with your PDF File.

I recreate new PDF file after all changing in data, like "Place of inspection", "Date of inspection", "Name of inspector" etc... i have many rows with different parameters. I see all changes in PDF file directly in Drive folder , but i dont see it if i go to this pdf file from my App (I have "file path" row with path. I see only first created version without changes. I dont use timestamp becouse i want recreate version i dont create all times new document in Drive folder .Sorry for my broken English and thaks for attention.

The problem you're running into is a common pitfall, stemming from the fact that your AppSheet app is using a cache service to try and make things efficient and run faster.
When you open a file in your AppSheet app for the first time, the file is downloaded from wherever and then stored on your device for 6 hours.
When you make changes to the file, unfortunately the file is not updated in the cache.
There is no mechanism that triggers to all devices that have ever opened the app that they then need to discard their current version of the file and download the new one. (You can see how that might be a bit of a heavy thing, with a whole bunch of pitfalls and problems to make that a smooth running thing 100% of the time. That's why they haven't made it, and they just stick with the fact that it's stored in cache for 6 hours.)

After the 6 hours elapses, you will see the changes inside the file if you try and open it again.
You can rest assured though, whenever you use that file for an email or something, whenever you send it out, the system will use the file from the data source not what you have cached on your device. It can be a little disconcerting when you open the file after you just made changes and you don't see any changes, I totally feel you on that. 
